# options for areas in apostrophe apos-widgets

Tags: javascript, apostrophe-cms

I want to create a sort of a wrapper widget - one that would have two areas, each with same available widgets. I configure it [like it was described in documentation](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/schema-guide.html#code-area-code), but it seems that the options object from `index.js` isn't passed.

If in `index.js` I have:

```
module.exports = {
    extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
    name: 'block-full-two',
    label: 'Fullscreen block',
    addFields: [{
            name: 'left',
            type: 'area',
            label: 'Left area',
            options: {
                widgets: {
                    'apostrophe-rich-text': {(...)}
                }
            },
            contextual: true
        }
        (...)
    ]
}
```

and in `widget.html`:

```
{{ apos.area(data.widget, 'left') }}
```

then area gets created, but when I click the plus icon, the list of available widgets is empty. But when I pass the widgets directly in `widget.html`: `{{ apos.area(data.widget, 'left', { widgets: {...}}) }}`, it works.
Is there something I've been doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've opened an issue for this in github as this has come up internally https://github.com/punkave/apostrophe/issues/1096

For now, you should explicitly pass those options right into the template.